# JQuery click seemingly being triggered on all buttons of same class

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a series of HTML links, all with the same class but with unique ID's - the ID contains a database ID.

When a button is clicked (as detected by a click on a button of that class) - it calls an ajax script to delete from the database using the ID passed on the link.

I can't replicate it but I am getting numerous reports of all items being deleted - as if someone had clicked every link on the page (but with assurances they haven't). I can see from backups that the data used to be there and there is no other code in the system that deletes from this table.

There is validation on the PHP script to ensure a user can only delete their own items.

Does anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks

Ben

Example:

HTML:

```
<a class="boatpic_delete" id="boatpicdelete_btn_1">Delete</a>
<a class="boatpic_delete" id="boatpicdelete_btn_2">Delete</a>
<a class="boatpic_delete" id="boatpicdelete_btn_3">Delete</a>
```

Jquery:

```
 $(".boatpic_delete").live("click",function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        id = id.replace("boatpicdelete_btn_", "");
        var tile = $("#boatpic_tile_"+id);

        data = "action=picdelete&id="+id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: pathToDashboard + "/editboat/ajax_boatpics.php",
            data : data,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response)
            {
                if(response && response.success == true)
                {                    
                    tile.remove();
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Error, unable to delete");               
                }  
            },
            error: function(res){
                alert("Error, unable to delete");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Key problem is with your code from replacing the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".boatpic_delete").click(function(){
```

instead of first line.

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7wowfvu5/1/)**

Also instead of this weird solution to get id, you can use `data` attribute like this:

```
<a class="boatpic_delete" id="boatpicdelete_btn_1" data-id="1">Delete</a>
<a class="boatpic_delete" id="boatpicdelete_btn_2" data-id="2">Delete</a>
<a class="boatpic_delete" id="boatpicdelete_btn_3" data-id="3">Delete</a>
```

And get `id` using `.data`:

```
var id = $(this).data("id");
```

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7wowfvu5/2/)**

Comment: Fantastic, thank you, I'll make those changes and see if we get any more instances of this happening over the next few days.

Comment: Hello, will do but I'll give it a couple of days first just to see if we get any more instances of it happening. I can't replicate the error so can't be sure unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the delete button and on-click function (i.e. `$(".boatpic_delete").click(function(){}`) are generated by jQuery. if so, and you are generating them multiple times, the buttons will trigger the on-click function multiple times.

For example, you generate 3 buttons and 3 on-click functions, the last button that is generated will only have one correspondent on-click function, the second will have two, the first will have 3.

If this is the case, you should either avoid generating the same on-click function multiple times, or use the button id rather than the class.